How select query from record count double in MS Access
I'm trying to select query from row count double based on ID and DATE in MS Access.
I want to keep it as a single query. What are the possibilities of this being applied? Or another method?
Please guide me, thanks
Table Absen



ID
DATE
TIME
INOUT




5008
28-Apr-24
08:00
IN


5008
28-Apr-24
17:00
OUT


5009
29-Apr-24
08:00
IN


5009
29-Apr-24
17:00
OUT


5010
29-Apr-24
08:00
IN



Table MASTERID



ID
NAMEID
POSITIONID




5008
A
STAFF


5009
B
STAFF


5010
C
STAFF



I used this SQL code which did not produce anything:
SELECT 
    ABSEN.ID, MASTERID.NAMEID AS NAMEID, ABSEN.DATE, 
    MASTERID.POSITIONID AS POSITIONID, ABSEN.TIME, ABSEN.INOUT, 
    COUNT(*) AS Expr1
FROM 
    ABSEN 
INNER JOIN 
    MASTERID ON ABSEN.ID = MASTERID.ID
GROUP BY 
    ABSEN.ID, MASTERID.NAMEID, ABSEN.DATE, MASTERID.POSITIONID, 
    ABSEN.TIME, ABSEN.INOUT, ABSEN.DATE
HAVING 
    (((COUNT(*)) > 1));

Desired output



ID
NAMEID
DATE
TIME
INOUT




5008
A
28-Apr-24
08:00
IN


5008
A
28-Apr-24
17:00
OUT


5009
B
29-Apr-24
08:00
IN


5009
B
29-Apr-24
17:00
OUT




Tricky how you want a single query... Watch out what you ask for because it is kind of impossible to do that without subqueries.
By the way, I am guessing you want the IDs where the INOUT has an OUT. And then order it by ID and TIME.
select a.ID, MASTERID.NAMEID, a.DATE, a.TIME, a.INOUT
from ABSEN a INNER JOIN MASTERID ON a.ID = MASTERID.ID
where exists(select 1 from ABSEN a2 where a.ID=a2.ID and  a2.INOUT='OUT')
order by ID, DATE, TIME

sorry to do this to you but I am certain that works in SQL Server, this is a 100% solution.
where a.ID = (select a2.ID from ABSEN a2 where 
          a.ID=a2.ID and a2.INOUT='OUT')


Order by Date is also required. Nice answer. Upvoted.

@KeithL , Thank you for your perfect answer. I make your answer look like this  where exists(select 1 from ABSEN a2 where a.ID=a2.ID) order by a.ID,a.DATE  result is same.

@KeithL , May I ask if the SQL code from your answer if I want to select a query record that is more than 2 records with order by a.ID,a.DATE How can I do by adapting the SQL code of your answer?. Please Guide me

More than 2 of an ID regardless of date and time and inout? Can each ID be associated with multiple dates?

That "100% solution" is not working in Access.

@June7 , This is the answer that the postion first answer post produced the desired result

Consider: SELECT ABSEN.*, MASTERID.NameID FROM MASTERID INNER JOIN ABSEN ON MASTERID.ID = ABSEN.ID WHERE ABSEN.ID IN(SELECT ID FROM ABSEN GROUP BY ID HAVING Count(ID)>2);

@June7 , Thanks for your answer SELECT ABSEN.*, MASTERID.NameID FROM MASTERID INNER JOIN ABSEN ON MASTERID.ID = ABSEN.ID WHERE ABSEN.ID IN(SELECT ID FROM ABSEN GROUP BY ID HAVING Count(ID)>1); Answer For this post and I make new post so you can answer with SELECT ABSEN.*, MASTERID.NameID FROM MASTERID INNER JOIN ABSEN ON MASTERID.ID = ABSEN.ID WHERE ABSEN.ID IN(SELECT ID FROM ABSEN GROUP BY ID HAVING Count(ID)>2); link

To change logic to a count>1 you change the exists to exists(select 1 from ABSEN a2 where a.ID=a2.ID having count(*) > 1). Looking for an OUT should be faster though especially if the column is indexed.

To change logic to a count>1 you change the exists to exists(select a.ID from ABSEN a2 where a.ID=a2.ID group by a.ID having count(*) > 1). Looking for an OUT should be faster though especially if the column is indexed.
